# How does PTR and normal Overwatch mix?

Tags: overwatch

Any experience I earn, any lootboxes, any levels I gain in the PTR, do these apply in the normal Overwatch regions or are they PTR (Public Test Region - where updates go live before they are pushed to the actual game) specific ?

I remember hearing players getting gold drops and then going "aww man shame this is PTR and I wont get the item"

Comment: Neither the question nor the answer mentions what PTR is. Luckily, Google tells me it's Public Test Region, which appears to be for public tests of new patches.

Comment: @DCShannon No offence nor is it personal: If you don't know what PTR is in the context of Overwatch, most likely you're note qualified to provide any sort of answer.

Comment: I'm not sure how to respond to that. What does that have to do with anything? People intending to answer aren't the only ones who read a question, and you can't know if you intend to answer until you finish reading. This is an Overwatch question. I look at Overwatch questions. Other people who play Overwatch look at Overwatch questions. I'm not familiar with PTR, so I didn't even know what the question was about. I had to look it up. I left a note for anyone else in the same situation. I would *hope* you would improve your post by adding that clarification, but it's not wholly necessary.

Comment: @DCShannon I meant from the point of view of a potential answerer "If you don't know it, you're not fit to answer" But I can see what you mean and why you left the note so I included my own to the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything you get you on the PTR server, Levels and drops, stays on the PTR Server. So yes they are specific and do not transfer over to the "proper" Overwatch servers.

The FAQ on the overwatch page gives the answer [Source](https://playoverwatch.com/en-us/blog/20157263)

> Q. Will any progress I make on the PTR transfer over to the live game?
>
> A. No. Any progression earned during the PTR—including levels,
>   achievements, stats, skill ratings, loot boxes (including rewards from
>   loot boxes), currency (including Competive Points), and cosmetic items
>   unlocked with currency—will not transfer over to the live game.